# How to add a column in R, if a value from a matrix exists in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices x and y:

```
x
  1    4    7   10
  2    5    8   11
  3    6    9   12

y
1
4
3
6
```

Now I want to check that if the value from first column of `x` exist in `y` then it should add one more column to `x` and add `yes` in that and if not then add `non` in that and store in a third matrix called m.

Basically I should get the answer like:

```
m
1    4    7   10    yes
2    5    8   11    non
3    6    9   12    yes
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix "x" and your vector "y" to be:

```
x <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), .Dim = 3:4)
x
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
y <- c(1, 4, 3, 6)
```

You can just use `apply` to compare each row of "x" to your vector "y". Use `cbind` to add the result of that comparison as a new column to a new `matrix` named "m". A value of "1" means `TRUE` (or "yes") and a value of "0" means `FALSE` (or "non").

```
m <- cbind(x, apply(x, 1, function(z) any(z %in% y)))
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10    1
# [2,]    2    5    8   11    0
# [3,]    3    6    9   12    1
```

If you really wanted "yes" and "non" values, I would recommend that you use a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix` since a `matrix` can only contain one type of value while a `data.frame` can have different classes of data in each column.